# Select from multiple tables with laravel fluent query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm re-writing some PHP/MySQL to work with Laravel. One thing I would like to do is make the DB queries more succinct [with the Fluent Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent) but I'm a bit lost:

```
SELECT p.post_text, p.bbcode_uid, u.username, t.forum_id, t.topic_title, t.topic_time, t.topic_id, t.topic_poster
FROM phpbb_topics t, phpbb_posts p, phpbb_users u
WHERE t.forum_id = 9
AND p.post_id = t.topic_first_post_id
AND u.user_id = t.topic_poster
ORDER BY t.topic_time
DESC LIMIT 10
```

This queries a phpbb forum and gets posts:
[image]

How could I re-write this to make use of the Fluent Query Builder syntax?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Not tested but here is a start**

```
return DB::table('phpbb_topics')
    ->join('phpbb_posts', 'phpbb_topics.topic_first_post_id', '=', 'phpbb_posts.post_id')
    ->join('phpbb_users', 'phpbb_topics.topic_poster', '=', 'phpbb_users.user_id')
    ->order_by('topic_time', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get(array(
        'post_text',
        'bbcode_uid',
        'username',
        'forum_id',
        'topic_title',
        'topic_time',
        'topic_id',
        'topic_poster'
    ));
```

Comment: There is an option like below(tested in 5.3)-
->get(array('phpbb_topics.*',
                   'username',
                   'phpbb_posts.post_text'
                  )

Comment: this one solved my question. how to link this answer to my question? EDIT: I got it

Answer (score 5):

```
return DB::table(DB::raw('phpbb_topics t, phpbb_posts p, phpbb_users u')) 
->select(DB::raw('p.post_text, p.bbcode_uid, u.username, t.forum_id, t.topic_title, t.topic_time, t.topic_id, t.topic_poster'))
->where('phpbb_topics.topic_first_post_id', '=', 'phpbb_posts.post_id')
->where('phpbb_users', 'phpbb_topics.topic_poster', '=', 'phpbb_users.user_id')
->order_by('topic_time', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: Use distinct(), otherwise, it will give a repetitive data as a base on the tables count