# Getting parent json data in child level loop. (Laravel Vue js)

Tags: json, laravel, api, vue.js, axios

I have API data which I get from controller using

```
return parent::with('children')->get();
```

it gives me this:

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"George",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":4,
            "parent_id":"1",
            "name":"Glory"
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "parent_id":"1",
            "name":"Susan"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Robin",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":9,
            "parent_id":"2",
            "name":"Luke"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I can display it after fetching with axios like this:

```
    George has 2 children:
        1. Glory
        2. Susan
    Robin has 1 child:
        1. Luke
```

Now my goal is to display it like this:

```
    Name   | parent's name 
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Glory  | George
    Susan  | George
    Luke   | Robin
```

is there a way to achieve it in `vue js` or in `contoller`, `models` or anyewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from here:
[Select from multiple tables with laravel fluent query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463921/select-from-multiple-tables-with-laravel-fluent-query-builder/14465123#14465123)

so, i changed this:

```
return parent::with('children')->get();
```

to this:

```
  return DB::table('parent')
        ->join('children', 'parent_id', '=', 'parent.id')
        ->get(array(
            'name',
            'parent_name'
        ));
```

but first i changed the `name` field in `parent` table to `parent_name`

Answer (score 0):

Define the reverse relationship between Children and Parent, in which you will return the parent model with every children; and then in your controller you return all record that have a non-null parent with their parents

```php
return Model::where("parent_id", "<>", null)->with("parent")->get();
```

and then in your VueJS app you will have a JSON response of all children models along with their parents.

Comment: these are my current relationships:
`return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\parent', 'parent_id', 'id');` and `return $this->hasMany('App\Models\children');`. it gives me new field named `parent` and all the values are NULL.

Comment: are ```parent``` and ```children``` defined models of your application?

Comment: yes. would be easier if the parent model is deleted and move the data to children. but i'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is anymore! What do you mean by deleting the parent and moving data to children? Note that, as far as I can tell, you are dealing with a recursive relationship, and thus using a single table with recursive relationships would be much more efficient.

Comment: that's what i meant move the parent into children. delete the parent table and use only one table.

Comment: yes that should be the way to go, create one single table with a nullable Foreign Key called "parent_id", and then use that foreign key to define your parent and children relationships.

Comment: you are right. i can get data using your suggestion above but the format is still nested json which both parent and children can't be looped in the same row.

Comment: There is no point in flattening your json this way, in your vuejs app just iterate over the 1st level items in your json and render the 1st level with its parent->name. which will give you the output you are waiting for